# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^{n+(-1)^n}}$ Root test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm asking a question only about using root test. I only want to know if root test works here, I don't want to know if it's converges or diverges. if it's not work, then it means the limit is 0:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^{n+(-1)^n}}$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + \frac{1}{n}}}$

For the first one, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{10^{n+(-1)^n}})^{\frac{1}{n}}=0$. So the root test works

For the second one, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{n^{1 + \frac{1}{n}}})^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$. This is not working.

Again I want to say I am only checking if the root test works. It works one the first one. Is it right?

Comment: What do yo mean by "works" and "not working" ? The root test is *proven*.

Comment: Hint $\sum \frac 1{10^{n+(-1)^n}}< 10\sum \frac 1{10^n}$ and root test gives $\frac 1{10}$ not $0$...

Comment: The root test does not actually need a limit of $0$, and you do not have one, as @zwim has pointed out

Comment: On the second, your limit of $1$ is correct but it is approached from below so the root test does not give an answer.  On the question of convergence of the second series, you might want to consider $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n^{1+1/n}} = n^{-1/n}$ and use a different test